# How to make an interactive textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use textarea to show an array and its elements. Therefore i use `JSON.stringify` function. It works fine like this

```
 [
    {
        "content": {
            "objectTypeID": "FGHD",
            "_id": "singlePro"
    },
    {
        "content": {
            "objectTypeID": "KLM",
            "_id": "singlePro"
    }
]
```

Can i show an array like Chrome console with a textarea? Example;

```
1.  Array(2)
1.  0:{content: {…}}
2.  1:{content: {…}}
3.  length:2
```

And then when i click an element of array, it becomes open and shows its own elements.

If i can not do this with a textarea, how can i do that?

Comment: My question is how can i achieve this? It should not be with a text area.

Comment: You have to custom make your own behavior with buttons etc, not a textarea. Sounds like a pretty interesting project, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular div or list element might be better for what you want to achieve.
You can then use a library like jquery to toggle the display of the portions you want visible from ground up and the part you want hidden until after it is clicked

Alternatively, you can use vanilla (core) Javascript to toggle the display property. Though it might be much harder.

Alternatively, you can also learn a more mordern javascript front end library like Vue or angular to achieve your goal, although this is only advisable if you have some prior knowledge of basic Javascript

Comment: I use Angular 5. Thus you mean dynamic buttons and click them to open the array?

Comment: You can use dynamic buttons if you want but any clickable element will do just fine.
If you use and understand Angular, then it shouldn't be too much of a problem.
Based on my experience with Angularjs 1, your ng-repeat will come in handy here. And while iterating through the array, just enclose the parts you want hidden in possibly a span element and hide them , maybe with ng-show, until the ellipses are clicked.

Note, implementing for nested arrays will definitely be more difficult

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing for when I answer stackoverflow questions to help present the data in a more user friendly way.

https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL

It's not that complicated, but you will need to recursively iterate through your object progressively building the html nesting it as you go. And you wont' be able to present the data in a textarea, it will have to be native elements styled. If you want to make it editable I would recommend just using something like codemirror as that is really complicated.

I used lists to help with the formatting, then if I want to collapse the content I just use `display:none` on the parent `<ul>`

```js
const data = [{
    "content": {
      "objectTypeID": "FGHD",
      "_id": "singlePro"
    }
  },
  {
    "content": {
      "objectTypeID": "KLM",
      "_id": "singlePro"
    }
  }
]
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js?objectTypes=true"></script>
```

Here is an example of the minimum code to achieve what you are after, you could add the events to change the display, and add extra niceties.

```js
const output = document.querySelector('#output')
const data = [{
    "content": {
      "objectTypeID": "FGHD",
      "_id": "singlePro"
    }
  },
  {
    "content": {
      "objectTypeID": "KLM",
      "_id": 666
    }
  }
]

// get the type of thing
const type = thing => 
  Object.prototype.toString.call(thing)
    .replace(/\[object\s([^\]]+)\]/, '$1')
    .toLowerCase()

// element factory
const el = (name, className) => (...children) => {
  const el = document.createElement(name)
  el.className = `${className}`
  children.forEach(child => {
    if (typeof child === 'string' || typeof child === 'number') {
      child = document.createTextNode(child)
    }
    if (typeof child != null) {
      el.appendChild(child)
    }
  })
  return el
}

// elements for the app
const objectEl = el('ul', 'object')
const arrayEl = el('ul', 'array')
const propertyEl = el('li', 'property')
const keyEl = el('span', 'key')
const valueEl = el('span', 'value')

// parse object to html recursively
const parseHTML = val => {
  switch (type(val)) {
    case 'array':
      // wrap with ul.array and recursively call parse on the items
      return arrayEl(...val.map(x => parseHTML(x)))
    case 'object':
      // wrap with ul.object and recursively call parse on the properties
      return objectEl(
        ...Object.keys(val)
          .map(key => 
            propertyEl(
              keyEl(key),
              valueEl(parseHTML(val[key]))
            )
          )
      )
    case 'string':
      return el('span', 'string')(`"${val}"`)
    default:
      return el('span', type(val))(val)
  }
}

// parse the object and append it to the dom
output.appendChild(
  parseHTML(data)
)
```

```css
html {
  font-family: monospace;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.key {
  color: blue;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.key::after {
  content: ':';
}

.value .string {
  color: #a11;
}

.value .number {
  color: #164;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't answer with a link to code, add the code into your answer. If the link dies, so does your answer.

Comment: I imagine this question will be closed as it's to broad